# Cannot set permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android

I am new in android development and right now i struggle to get the current user location.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
Log.d("Check if permission", "permission is: " + permissionCheck);
```

Logd returns `permission is: -1`

What is it that i am doing so terribly wrong?

Using Android Studio, target-sdk is 23

Comment: Please show the code with your `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` call.

Comment: I am just checking if the permission is granted and nothing more in my code. Is this the problem?

Comment: If ~checkSelfPermission~ returns -1 then you don't have the permission and you need to request it. Make sure you are using ~requestPermissions~.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`checkSelfPermission()` will check whether the user has granted permission. If the check fails (-1 in your case), you then need to request permission from the user with `requestPermissions()`

Theres a good explanation of it, with an example of how to check, notify, and request permissions, in the android docs (http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request)

In case the link dies, here is what their code looks like:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

(Source: Android Developer Docs)